My wordpress plugin defaults to English (US) I would like it to default to English (UK)
I have written a Wordpress plugin which has been accepted into the repository:
https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/english-chess-data
I have noticed that the language it is listed as is English (US), however I am from the UK so the default text is actually English (UK) and this is where all of my users will be from, because the plugin is specific to Chess in England (which is within the United Kingdom).
Is there a way to specify the default langauge of a wordpress plugin?
I couldn't seem to be find anything about this in the developer handbook, there was a lot of information about adding more languages, but as it will only be used in one country I just wanted to change the default language to show correctly.
Here is what is shown on the plugins page on the wordpress website:


Unfortunately, there does not appear to be a way to change the default language away from EN-US, in the wordpress.org repository.
An email responce just recieved from plugins[at]wordpress.org has confirmed that the default of EN-US is an intentional policy process.

The submission is done in English US and then you will be able to translate it to any other language.

Which is a 'Whats That For (WTF)' eyebrow-raising assumption for a policy & process; because, it implies that all EN plugins are written in US style spelling and phrasing for the entire english language; nope, thats obviously not right.
However, the wordpress.org policy process for language translation does really appear to be setup as EN-US as the key. The translation glossaries for EN-GB Glossary & EN-AU Glossary have way to many 'z's and not enough 'u's in the 'Item' column. The 'Item' column being the EN-US term used as the official translation key.
Hence, it looks like the approach to anchor to just one flavour of english (like EN-US) might have been chosen to reduce the day-to-day activity noise and practical tooling implications of so many world-wide languages. By not anchoring to one flavour, the translation multiplication of "from x to" gets pretty messy.
Action Recommended: As the plugin author who is fluent in EN-GB, it looks  like you might be able to become a 'Translation Editor' for your own plugin for the EN-GB locale. Have a read through 'Plugin/Theme Author Translation Review/PTE Request' for step-by-step instructions.
Outcome: This would at least open up a way to get rid of the yellow bar at the top of the English Chess Data (EN-GB) plugin page.

[Done] The yellow bar is now gone from the top of the wordpress.org (en_GB) plugin page.
